# Continuing from where FFMPEG Stopped/Crashed

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion

I was turning an Image Sequence into a MKV Video with FFMPEG. A little over halfway done it stopped/crashed, it did not give an error message. Is there a way where I could continue from where it crashed (~Frame 90000) instead of redoing the whole thing?

What I had entered: (Video is ~159000 frames or ~44 minutes)

```
C:\Users\eric\Documents\ffmpeg-n4.4.1-win64-gpl-4.4\bin\ffmpeg -framerate 60 -i E:\Coding\openGLFractals\Frame-%d.png -c:v libx264rgb -r 60 -pix_fmt rgb24 -refs 15 -crf 4 E:\Videos\330-Fractal\FF330.mkv
```

Later it displayed `C:\Users\eric>` meaning the program stopped/crashed (FFMPEG had saved 9GB or 57% of the video at that point)

```
frame=90214 fps= 11 q=12.0 size= 9120256kB time=00:25:02.38 bitrate=49729.7kbits/s speed=0.188x
C:\Users\eric>
```

Comment: You may encode the second part and use concat demuxer for concatenating the two parts without re-encodig. For selecting the first image file, you may use `start_number` argument. (If it is just one case, I suppose you better re-encode everything).